# алгоритм diff'a деревьев

Tags: алгоритм, дерево, структуры-данных, diff

Подскажите какие есть алгоритмы сравнения деревьев и разного рода многомерных структур.
В частности интересует json.

т.е. если у нас есть две структуры A и B.

Я хочу получить разницу между A к B ( назовем ее Ab ), и B к А (Ba).

что бы при слиянии ( || ) получилось так:

```
B||Ab = A

A||Ba = B
```

Answer (score 0):

Самое простое, что приходит на ум, так это измерение редакционного расстояния между вершинами деревьев. То есть, можно посчитать число вставленных, удалённых и заменённых вершин.

Вот пара ссылок на данную тему: https://medium.com/f-ing-about/f-tree-diff-algorithm-5b7f9c85beac

[https://thume.ca/2017/06/17/tree-diffing](https://thume.ca/2017/06/17/tree-diffing/)